# Android - using activity getters from custom RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got the following classes:

**MatchActivity.java:**

```
public void setDart1(int playerIndex, int points) {
        getDart1().set(playerIndex, points);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getDart1() {
        return dart1;
    }

    public void setDart2(int playerIndex, int points) {
        getDart2().set(playerIndex, points);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getDart2() {
        return dart2;
    }

    public void setDart3(int playerIndex, int points) {
        getDart3().set(playerIndex, points);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getDart3() {
        return dart3;
    }
```

**MatchActivityPlayerAdapter.java:**

```
package de.tkirchmann.myaveragev3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class MatchActivityPlayerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchActivityPlayerAdapter.MatchActivityPlayerRowViewHolder> {

    private final List<Player> playerList;
    private final Match match;
    private Context context;

    MatchActivityPlayerAdapter(List<Player> playerList, Match match) {
        this.playerList = playerList;
        this.match = match;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MatchActivityPlayerAdapter.MatchActivityPlayerRowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.match_activity_row_layout, parent, false);
        return new MatchActivityPlayerRowViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MatchActivityPlayerAdapter.MatchActivityPlayerRowViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Player player = playerList.get(position);
        MatchActivity matchActivity = new MatchActivity();

        holder.nameTextView.setText(player.getPlayerName());
        holder.pointsTextView.setText(matchActivity.getRemainingPoints().get(position));
        holder.dart1.setText(matchActivity.getDart1().get(position));
        holder.dart2.setText(matchActivity.getDart2().get(position));
        holder.dart3.setText(matchActivity.getDart3().get(position));
        holder.dartsCombined.setText(matchActivity.getDartsCombined().get(position));
        /*holder.averageTextView.setText(matchActivity.getAverage().get(position));*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return playerList.size();
    }

    class MatchActivityPlayerRowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView nameTextView, pointsTextView, averageTextView, dart1, dart2, dart3, dartsCombined;

        public MatchActivityPlayerRowViewHolder(View playerRowView) {
            super(playerRowView);
            final ConstraintLayout playerRowRootLayout = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.match_player_row_root_layout);
            nameTextView = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            pointsTextView = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.points);
            averageTextView = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.average);
            dart1 = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.dart1);
            dart2 = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.dart2);
            dart3 = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.dart3);
            dartsCombined = playerRowView.findViewById(R.id.last_darts_combined);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder()` method in the custom adapter I want to set the texts of my views by getting the values from the lists via getters from my activity. But I am getting a IndexOutOfBoundsException, so I propably don't have a correct reference/context when calling the getters.

How can I get the correct context/reference to my activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
((YourActivityName) itemView.getContext()).getDart1();
```

and then so on for other getters. You can use any public method using this.

Comment: What do you mean by ```itemView```?

Comment: `itemView` is the context of the view or a layout in the recycler view. Which in other words tell's us the context of the activity it is being displayed in

Comment: Why can't I access all getters from my MainActivity? The one I need does not show up while some others do. Edit: Never mind, I have to declare the method as public.